# multiple media queries declaration on responsive design

Tags: css, media-queries

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 480px) {
    #something{display:none !important;
}
```

I use this as my mobile css set, but it effect my elements still in larger screen size (more than 480px), do I have to declare another set of media queries on larger size.

Comment: `min-device-width: 480` affects all devices with device width **greater than/equal to** 480 px.

Comment: You don't need to declare another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following :-

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    #something{display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: why do you write something inside your example? it's confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you do... Try something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 480px){}
@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 720px){}
@media (max-width: 720px){}
@media (max-width: 940px) and (min-width: 720px){}
```

Comment: The question here is *do I have to declare another?* not *Can I ...*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for every range you need to declare,
you declared only the larger than 480px, if you want a range, do it like this: 
@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 480px)and (max-width:480px) {}

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14815287)

Comment: @FabianSchultz, I am not criticizing, this is the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Every device is following some specific range of viewport like mobile devices specifically follow 320px to 480px view more than that is followed by tabs from 480px to 650px morover some small screen sized laptops uses upto 840px viewport , normal 13-15 inches laptop uses viewport of upto 1350px and screens bigger that uses 1920px viewport so you declare media queries accordingly
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px){`enter code here`}
`@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 720px){`enter code here`}
@media (min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 950px){`enter code here`}
@media (min-width: 950px) and (max-width: 1150px){`enter code here`}
@media (min-width: 1150px) and (max-width: 1350px){`enter code here`}
@media (min-width: 1350px) and (max-width: 1920px){`enter code here`}